# Mark all code in a file as comments

Tags: comment

Sometimes, i wish to mark all code in a file as comments. I tried putting all code between the markups `#||` and `#||`. On file loading, emacs threw the error,

```
Invalid read syntax: #
```

I can't use `#+nil`, because the file has multiple statements and not a single function. Is there a way to comment?

Comment: What about selecting the region you want to comment first, then calling the `comment-region` function?

Comment: This will do it `C-x h M-;`

Comment: As @kaushalmodi suggests, you can use `M-;` after selecting the buffer text. But be aware that if you use `M-;` on a region that is already completely commented out then it becomes uncommented, instead of becoming nested in a new comment level. I generally use `comment-region` instead of `M-;`, as it is more flexible (IMO) in this regard. It always comments, except with `C-u`, where it removes a level of commenting. (Bind `comment-region` to a key.)

Comment: i did see, that `M-x comment-region` retains existing comments as it is and just adds two extra semicolons in the line beginning. But i didn't know `C-h M-;` will uncomment already commented lines.

Comment: @MadhavanKumar `M-;` will uncomment only if every line in the selected region is already a comment. For your use case, if your whole file is already commented out, `M-;` will uncomment it. But then, why would you want to comment an already completely commented out file? Let's say you have a commented line and an uncommented line. Now if you select those 2 lines and do `M-;`, you will end up with that first line double commented and the second line single commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the whole buffer (`C-x h`) and comment it (`M-;`).